# How to create rownum in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Below is the example that I want to do:

```
declare @table table(col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10));
insert into @table(col1,col2) values ('a1','5340');
insert into @table(col1,col2) values ('a1','3340');
insert into @table(col1,col2) values ('a1','9185340');
insert into @table(col1,col2) values ('b1','1110');
```

Here is a table and sample data. Now how I want result is as below:

```
select * from @table

col1    col2      seq
a1  5340       1
a1  3340       2
a1  9185340    3
b1  1110       1
```

If you noticed here, the SEQ is reset back again to 1 for new value of COL1. And I don't want to change the order of value in COL2. ie. value 5340 should be 1 and so on.

This is just a sample data. But the real data comes from another table so the values are not fixed to only 4 rows.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank You

Comment: You want the `seq` value to be based on insertion order?

Comment: Exactly. I want SEQ value based on insertion. Actually first the data that has COL1 = a1 will be inserted so its sequence is 1,2,3..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a regular `IDENTITY` column as your SEQ:

```
declare @table table(raw_seq int IDENTITY(1,1), col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10));
```

then use

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY raw_seq) AS seq
```

In order to get the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `row_number()` analytic function.

```
select
  col1,
  col2,
  row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) seq
from
  table
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER is an analytic function, not an aggregate -- or you'd have needed a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @OMG - true.  Also, left off the parens.

Comment: This doesn't work the way I want. Because it orders the value in COL2. The result set I got from your statement is as below:

Comment: hid ht seq                                                        a1 3340 1                                                          a1 5320 2 etc,   the data on col2 is arranged by asc order which I don't want. I want that column untouched.